# How do I do a linebreak inside a table?

Tags: tables, mathjax

I have some  equations inside a table slot, but I want to linebreak. [image]

In my specific problem I want to create a Linebreak after the equation
$$C_{3}=M_{1}+d$$

How can I create this linebreak in a table?
thanks

Comment: Are you using LaTeX or mathjax? The syntax may be similar, but the underlying rendering engine is completely different. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You've given no indication how you'll construct the table. My answer therefore has to use a fairly minimalist `\parbox` approach.

[image]

You can place the `\parbox` directive inside a suitably wide cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$C_3=m_1+d\setminus M_3 =$} % ca. 3.2cm

\begin{document}
\parbox{\mylen}{\centering $C_3=m_1+d\setminus M_3 =$ $H_2+dM_4=F_1+d$}
\end{document}
```